# How to read a JSON object response from GET request in Angular 9?

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I have a `GET` request that returns the following JSON object:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "timestamp": 1591353365,
    "base": "EUR",
    "date": "2020-06-05",
    "rates": {
        "AED": 4.16005,
        "AFN": 85.969034,
        "ALL": 124.045327,
        "AMD": 540.380668,
        "ANG": 2.009928,
    }
}
```

To get this response in angular, I have a service that uses the API to retrieve this object using `http.get()`:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ForexService {

  api_key = 'my personal key' //Can't give away the key

  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) { }

  latestRates() {
    return this._http.get('http://data.fixer.io/api/latest?access_key='+this.api_key);
  }
}
```

And I have a component file that subscribes to this service observable:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ForexService } from "../forex.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-forexapi',
  templateUrl: './forexapi.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./forexapi.component.css']
})
export class ForexapiComponent implements OnInit {

  data:Array<any>;
  constructor(private forex: ForexService) {
    console.log('Forex component constructor called');
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.forex.latestRates().subscribe(data => this.data = data);
    }
  }
```

When I do this, I get the error that `The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?`

How do I retrieve data from this JSON object? The `rates` is yet another object and is of variable length. I can't seem to retrieve that data.

Comment: either declare  `data:Array<any>=[]` then push  ,`this.data.push(data)` or  declare `data:any={}`.

Comment: That just pushed the undefined variable in the data array. I still can't parse it :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, it was an async reply so can be solved using the async-wait method.

This is how I changed the code in service:

```
latestRates(base: string = "USD"): Promise<any> {
    //return this._http.get('http://data.fixer.io/api/latest? access_key='+this.api_key+'&base='+base).toPromise();
    return this._http.get('https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest?base='+base).toPromise();
  }
```

And the receiving function looks like:

```
data:any;
async requestData(base) {
    this.data = await this.forex.latestRates(base);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The good side of using Angular 2+ is that it uses `TypeScript` and you are able to do also strong `typing` in your code, for example to define return type of your latestRate like this:

```
 latestRates(): Observable<Rate[]> {
 return this._http.get('http://data.fixer.io/api/latest?access_key='+this.api_key)
    .map(result=>result.rates)

 }
```

Also create a model of your `rate`, something like `rate.model.ts` and define it as the response object `rate` (that object that you are getting from your API EndPoint):

```
export interface ResponseObject {
  success: number;
  timestamp: string;
  base: string;
  date: Date;
  rates: Rate;
 }
export interface Rate  {
    aed: number;
    afn: number;
    all: number;
}
```

Save it as `rate.model.ts`. After that, in your ngOnInit:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
      this.forex.latestRates().subscribe(rates => this.data = rates);
}
```

Side note: try to avoid using `any` as `type`

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't unnderstand the part where I create a model of rate. Could you please explain it a bit more clearly?

Comment: @smithnblack A class is unsuitable for declaring a type that represents an HTTP response because the deserialized JSON values that result from HTTP requests will never be instances of a class. An interface is a perfect candidate for it.

Comment: How do I define a variable for the `rates` object inside the JSON object `data`?

Answer (score 1):

issue is with your `data` variable datatype in `ForexapiComponent` ;

Your return response has data as objects but you declared  `data` variable as array of items, so Typescript will be expecting array of items instead of objects

for a quick fix you can change type of `data`  to  any  like this `data:any`

Comment: But when I do that, it doesn't store any data and shows that data is undefined. Console error is:
`ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'rates' of undefined`

Comment: try `this.forex.latestRates().subscribe(data => this.data = JSON.parse(data));`

Comment: data is not a string, it's a JSON object. How do I parse a JSON object? I'm new to javascript. I don't know how to do that :(

Comment: JSON.parse will parse as js object..that's what i mentioned in previous comment

Comment: This is the error:  ```Argument of type 'Object' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
this.forex.latestRates().subscribe(data => this.data = JSON.parse(data));```

Answer (score 1):

you are defining `data` as `data:Array<any>;` i.e. an array

But the data you are getting is an `JSON Object`

Use `data:any;`